# How can i avoid same image name at the point of upload to filesystem

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, unique

I have a form whereby Users upload pictures as part of their registration process. But my issue is that, users that save the names of their image with the same name might cause some issues when they view the profile pictures. How can i make the picture name unique at the point of uploading to the filesystem..

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider to rename the file to <userID>.jpg?

Comment: See php's function [tmpfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) function.

All files should be uploaded with a temporary filename. Then, you do something with it. In this case, when the user has registered, rename the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this helps

```
$t = uniqid();
$filename='user-'.$t;
echo $filename; // user-1335601088 (always a different name)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work - there are only 60 different potential values it can ever end up as because `date('s')` will always return a value between 0-59

Comment: I have no idea what `mktime(uniqid())` will return you. Why don't you just use `rand()` or `uniqid()` on their own?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited the answer and just forgot to remove the `mkTime`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using one of the following schemes:

- make the filename a function of the username/userid
- make the filename a random value
- make the filename a function of the file content (e.g. an MD5 checksum)

Comment: If i'm to use the userID option, then the uploading will come a step after i've registered the user. Or is there a better way of doing this all as one process.?

Comment: How to handle images that get uploaded by users to don't complete the registration process is a tricky problem. You'd have to do some kind of cleanup or just change the process as you suggested and only let people do this uploading after they've registered.